# pnp search filter and search result v4

Tags: search, filter, pnp, sharepoint-list-filter

Has anyone used pnp search filter and search result. I have a choice field "LearningStack" in 7 different list and 6 different libraries. The idea is to have a page where I can display "Learning Stack" as a drop down or card and when selected I like result to filtered by the value. For example, if someone selects "Workplace Posters" then it should display items from all of the lists and libraries where "Learning Stack" -equal "workflow posters". I need to find a good solution and it's so hard to find a solution. I am using modern page (SPO)

Answer (score 0):

Its a little unclear, what your question is for me. But if you are asking if pnp search webpart can let your users filter on a value from a drop down and show results from multiple libraries and list then the answer is a definite yes!

In short to achieve this I would recommend to map your "LearningStack" column to a RefinableString in the SharePoint search schema (done by an admin), and then include the RefinableString in the Pnp search result webpart and the pnp filter webpart.